# Remove image icon in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using an css style "subscribe" ,and I used in submit button. This looks good in all browsers expect ie . In ie there is an image which overlap on that. How to remove that?
http://postimage.org/image/o5stss847/

```
<input class="button" id="subscribe" type="image" /></center>
```

Comment: Your input is of type image but has no `src` attribute.

Comment: i am using image on css code because it is an sprite image

Comment: only in IE? it seems, the problem is in chrome also, right?

Comment: no only in ie. works fine in chrome and mozilla

Comment: Then why not just use a input submit

Comment: why are you using input for images? you will trigger ``subscribe`` function under this image?